# How to elegantly pass long type name to template parameter?

Tags: c++, templates, types, c++17

I am using c++17. I have some code that looks like this:

```
typedef uint64_t z_hash_t;

struct MoveEdge {
  uint64_t dest_hash;
  uint32_t times_played;
  uint32_t move_key;
  std::string pgn_move;
};

struct OpeningTablebase
{
  std::unordered_map<z_hash_t, std::shared_ptr<std::vector<MoveEdge>>> m_tablebase;
};

void foo(){
    typedef std::__1::unordered_map<z_hash_t, std::__1::shared_ptr<std::__1::vector<MoveEdge>>>::iterator tablebase_iter;
    auto root = m_tablebase.find(m_root_hash);

    std::queue<tablebase_iter> to_visit;
    to_visit.push(root);

}
```

Is there a better way to pass the type of `root` to the template parameter for `std::queue`? Using `typedef` to create the alias `tablebase_iter` seems to be a bit better than pasting the whole name in the parameter, but I was wondering if there was a more concise/elegant way to do so.

I'm not sure of the syntax, I hoped I could do something like this:

```
std::queue<typeof root> to_visit;
```

Comment: [`decltype`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/decltype)?

Comment: `template<typename T>foo(){std::queue<T> to_visit; ...`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You almost got it. You are looking for [`decltype`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/decltype):

```
void foo()
{
    auto root = m_tablebase.find(m_root_hash);
    //         VVVVVVVVVVVVV
    std::queue<decltype(root)> to_visit;
    to_visit.push(root);
}
```